# React JS onClick handler firing upon render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When trying to setup an onKeyPress handler to log a user in when they press enter on a username/password text field my onClick handler is firing twice for some reason.

When clicking the submit button it only fires once.
I only see it fire twice when pressing the enter key on the text field to trigger the onKeyPress event.

I am unsure why.
I am fairly confident I have the function and onClick bindings done properly.

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    onKeyPress(evt) {
        if (evt.key === "Enter") {
            console.log("Enter key detected");
            this.login();
        }
    }
    loginOnClick(evt) {
        console.log('Login.loginOnClick()');
        this.login();
    }
    login = async () => {
        return true;
    }
}


render()
{
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" onKeyPress={e => this.onKeyPress(e)} />
            <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.loginOnClick(e)}>Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: This is probably not your main problem, but your handlers aren't binded to the component's instance

Comment: If I changed it to handler = (e) => {} would I still need to explicitly bind it?

Comment: Nop. `arrow functions` have a lexical `this`.

Comment: Actually it's working as expecting or I understand your problem wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/L6r39oxq/1/

Comment: Press the enter key while focus is on the username textfield. The login button on click handler fires when it should not.